# Responsive Fixed-Nav?

Tags: css, navigation, fixed

I understand how to create a fixed nav menu.  The one I am designing has links to various anchor points on the page. What I do not understand is how to I have the menu items automatically indicate where I am on the page? Can this be done without JS?

This effect is found on many 1-page designs.  For instance:

http://www.thirdculturestudios.com/

http://kevinmheineman.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this without JavaScript, because CSS... well... cascades. The way those pages work is that each menu item has a class `.active` or similar, that is added when the item is clicked.

EDIT: I believe you're looking for jQuery's `scroll()` [(see here)](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) , where you can specify a function that takes place when the user scrolls. In this case, the function would check the `scrollTop` value and compare it to the `offset` of page sections, then add a class to the appropriate menu item.

A quick Google search of these terms will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Isaac and everyone else.  I am not sure if I phrased the question correctly.  What I do have is a fixed nav menu and it also has js attached to it for the smooth scrolling to the anchor points.  What I am trying to figure out is how the menu items automatically change as you scroll down through page (even without clicking on the menu item).  Notice the menu changing as you scroll through the site... http://www.thirdculturestudios.com/

Comment: Thanks Issac.  I'll take a look.  My JS are meager but we'll see what I can cobble together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do that in CSS. Both of the pages you link to involve adding/removing classes dynamically based on the `click` event. CSS has no way of dynamically adding classes.

If you're interested, here's how you could do the link highlighting depending on if it's clicked simply in jQuery:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

var a = $('#container a');
a.click(function() {
    a.removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H5rNM/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the jump using `<a name="resourceName" id="resourceName">` anchor tags.  But the smooth scrolling to the item needs javascript.

You just use `<a href="#resourceName">Text</a>` to just jump to it (non js world).

Edit: clarified grammar since I tried rereading it and realized it would be confusing the way I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

No can't be done without Javascript.